# Saving user settings to isolated storage

Tags: windows-phone-7

I checked out this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769510(v=VS.92).aspx

But when I run the default windows phone emulator from visual studio and check the checkbox, and then return a screen en then open my application again, the box is no longer checked.
Now, since this is an emulator I dont know if it also emulates local storage..if not I'd like to know that as well.

The example site also mentions this part:

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
 <local:AppSettings x:Key="appSettings"></local:AppSettings>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

But I get an error: Cannot create an instance of "AppSettings".

So how can I fix this? And how do I know something was actually saved.

My example application can be found here: 
http://www.wunderwedding.com/files/MyFirstWP7App.zip

Comment: I checked out your sample app and it works fine. I'm not sure about the designer error but I've gotten used to ignoring them.

Comment: Did it also work for you in the emulator? So: check the box, navigate back to homescreen and navigate again to settingspage, the box is still checked?

Comment: Yes, I only used the emulator and it worked every time.

Comment: it does work now, I updated the emulator and deleted the save files from C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\XDE
Thanks for checking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because instantiating ApplicationsSettings throws an exception. If you add the following to your constructor, you should be fine;

```
try
{
    settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
}
catch (System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException e)
{
    // handle exception
}
```